# Prove that the measure of the angle...

Tags: geometry

[image]

How can I prove that the measure of angle $EBC$ is $60$?

Thank you!

Comment: Is upper A angle 15 or 45?

Comment: Are we given that it is a square? Or any else info? Right angles?

Comment: Yes it is a square, I forgot to mention.

Comment: And the angle is 15, right?

Comment: Yes, it is 15 .

Comment: I don't see the use of left side of the figure. I will try coordinate.

Comment: Assume $AD = 1$. Drop a perpendicular from E to F on AD. Find the length of EF. Drop a perpendicular from E to G on BC. Find its length. Then the tangent of your angle is $EG/(1/2)$. (But this is the hard way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $I$ be the point in triangle $ABE$ such that $\angle IBA=\angle IAB=15^0$. Then $\triangle IBA=\triangle EAD$.It follows that $AE=AI$. Since $\angle IAE=60^0$, the triangle $IAE$ is an equilateral triangle. Then $IA=IE$. We have $\angle BIA=180^0-15^0-15^0=150^0$ and $\angle BIE=360^0-150^0-60^0=150^0$. This follows that $\triangle IBE=\triangle IBA$ and so $\angle IBE=\angle IBA=15^0$. Hence $\angle EBC=90^0-15^0-15^0=60^0$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

The two triangles with the $15^{\circ}$ angles are both isosceles. If you know that $ABCD$ is a square then they are, in fact, congruent triangles. That allows you to start putting little dashes on all of the sides of equal length. Then when two sides of a triangle with unknown angles have the same lengths for two of their sides you know that it's isosceles and know that two of its angles are equal.

Try it. You get to the answer pretty quickly.